# Web client upload will happen, Where?

Tags: c#, http

I've written a simple code. I don't understand, what happens here. Please explain to me, where will I find a given upload file

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string uri = "http://localhost:8080/sample.txt";
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string Filename = "F:\sample_test.txt/docx;
byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(uri, "POST", Filename);
```

Comment: What does the server side look like? Are you writing an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: I am writing a code now i am asking question at SO and now when i get the correct answer i leave SO, and get back again if i don't understand.

Comment: C# only. windows form application

Comment: @soundy: The Windows Forms application is probably the client application. But what is listening on port 8080? Is it IIS? Either you have a web application that accepts uploads or you'll need to write one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be your filename:

```
string Filename = "F:\sample_test.txt/docx/";
```

Change the forward slashes to blackslashes, and give an actual filename as well, not just the path:

```
string Filename = @"F:\sample_test.txt\docx\";
```

Or

```
string Filename = "F:\\sample_test.txt\\docx\\";
```

Actually, the filename as is doesn't make much sense - I'm not sure how `UploadFile` would process it, even with the slashes going the correct way, as you appear to have a filename followed by a directory...?  Shouldn't it actually be:

```
string Filename = @"F:\docx\sample_test.txt"?
```

It could be the URI - you're specifying the filename as well as the URI.

Did you look at the location specified in the URI?  http://localhost:8080/?

If it's not there, then try wrapping your code in a try-catch block to see if any exceptions are thrown:

```
try
{
     byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(uri, "POST", Filename);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // do something here - in the debugger, you can inspect ex.Message to see the exception
}
```

Comment: guys ,  F:\sample_test.txt/docx means F:\sample_test.txt or F:\sample_test.docx . i thought this only

Comment: content of F:\sample_test.txt file is not any where in uploaded uri http://localhost:8080/sample.txt

Comment: Never seen that before (doesn't mean it doesn't exist).  However, with the backslash `\` in the string, you either need to escape it with another `\` - like `\\` - or put the `@` in front of the string.

Comment: @soundy - then put the `client.UploadFile` in a try-catch block as I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with this clearly isn't your *real* code, as this line won't compile:

```
string Filename = "F:\sample_test.txt/docx/";
```

`\s` isn't a valid escape sequence However, assuming you had working code, what will happen is that your application would make an HTTP POST request with the contents of the file, to the given URI - in this case `http://localhost:8080/sample.txt`. It's *entirely* up to the server what it does with the request.

- It could save the file on disk somewhere
- It could save it to a database
- It could post it to another web service
- It could completely ignore the contents, and not save it anywhere

Nothing is guaranteed by the act of uploading the file - you're just making a request with some data.

Now if your URI *really* involves `localhost`, then it's uploading the file to the computer you're on - so you should be in control of what the web server listening on port 8080 is going to do with upload requests. Again, we can't *tell* you what it will do - it's up to the server.